# SQL RIGHT JOIN Won't Count Null Data

Tags: sql, sql-server

So, I have some data that needs to be count with RIGHT JOIN. The query look like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(trans_id) FROM database2..transaction a
RIGHT JOIN database1..sellers b
ON a.products = b.products
GROUP BY sellers
ORDER BY sellers
```

The result ends up perfectly like this one:

[image]

As you can see, there are 10 names on the result and there are 3 zero results because it was NULL data in my database.

And then I tried to add some conditions on the query, like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(trans_id) FROM database2..transaction a
    RIGHT JOIN database1..sellers b
    ON a.products = b.products
WHERE trans_status = 'success'
    GROUP BY sellers
    ORDER BY sellers
```

The result ends up differently:

[image]

It ended up with 6 results only. And the zero count on before was gone after I add up some conditions. Does that mean SQL only count existed data only even though I added up condition like that?

Comment: WHERE trans_status = 'success' AND TotalProducts IS NULL

Comment: People have problems enough with left join. Why make things even worse with right join?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find it much easier to follow `left join` rather than `right join`.  But your problem is that the `where` conditions should go in the `on` clause -- otherwise they turn the outer join in to an inner join:

```
SELECT COUNT(trans_id)
FROM database1..sellers s LEFT JOIN
     database2..transaction t
     ON s.products = t.products AND trans_status = 'success'
GROUP BY sellers
ORDER BY sellers;
```

I also encourage you to:

- Use table abbreviations for aliases (rather than generic letters such as "a" or "b").
- qualify all column names (I haven't done that, even though `trans_status` is obviously from `transaction`).
- `Left join` is preferable to `right join` because SQL `from` clauses are parsed from "left" to "right".

Comment: `left join` also has the advantage of being the join that is implemented on the database, and how the query will be rewritten by the optimizer.

Answer (score 3):

Your `WHERE` clause is applied after your `JOIN`. If you want the 0 counts to still show up, you should add it to your `JOIN` instead.

```
SELECT COUNT(trans_id) FROM database2..transaction a
    RIGHT JOIN database1..sellers b
    ON a.products = b.products
       AND trans_status = 'success'
    GROUP BY sellers
    ORDER BY sellers
```

Answer (score 1):

They were likely dropped by this condition: "WHERE trans_status = 'success'".

Instead of WHERE clause, try this condition in the ON clause of the JOIN. Something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(trans_id) FROM database2..transaction a
    RIGHT JOIN database1..sellers b
    ON a.products = b.products AND trans_status = 'success'
    GROUP BY sellers
    ORDER BY sellers
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(t2.trans_id)
 FROM  table1 t1
 RIGHT OUTER JOIN
       table2 t2
   ON  t2.products = t1.products
 WHERE t1.id IS NOT NULL
   OR  t2.trans_status = 'success'
 GROUP BY sellers
    ORDER BY sellers
;
```